# How to write content before and after the output of a JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I have JPSs that represent Components. I want to have these component JSPs write some HTML before and after the contents of the JSP is executed.

component.jsp

```
<@page session="false">
<%= "hello " + "world" %>
```

when this JSP/servlet is rendered, I want it to render:

```
<div class="component">
hello world
</div>
```

I want to be able to create various "wrappers", and depending on the JSP, include wrap the contents of the JSP with the correct content. If I want to change/augment the wrapper down the road, I want to only do it in one place (Could be 100s of components).

Can i do something with <@page extends="..."> possibly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What do you want is named: **tag files**. Introduced on JSP 2.0

With this approach you can write JSP tags using jsp, therefore you need to create a folder named `WEB-INF/tags`, and create a 'normal' jsp within this folder.

The tag that you want to create needs to have the following start instruction:
`<%@tag description="tag description" %>` in order to indicate this is a tag.

To use it you will need to reference the tags you want to use with the following instruction: `<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="custom"%>`

So, you can do something like:
WEB-INF/tags/myTag.tag

---

```
<%@tag description="hello tag" %>
<%@attribute name="name" required="false" type="java.lang.String"%>
<html><head></head><body>
<h1>Hello <%=name%></h1>
<jsp:doBody />
</body>
```

index.jsp

---

```
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="custom"%>
<custom:myTag name="My Name">this is the content</custom:myTag>
```

---

The result will be a page printing

```
<html><head></head><body>
<h1>Hello My Name</h1>
this is the content
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a *terrible* idea.  JSPs with scriptlets are 1998 technology.  *No one* writes these anymore.

If you must write JSPs, you're better off using JSTL and something like SiteMesh or Tiles to composite pages.

An even better idea would be to start moving towards something that might allow you to easily run a mobile solution alongside your web app.  Services and templates would be my preference over JSPs.